# How to list blog post from subdirectory wordpress install to the main site

Tags: blog-page, featured-post

I have decided to separate my main website and my blog with different Wordpress installs. I've installed my blog in the subdirectory (/blog/ folder) and my main Wordpress is only contained homepage and pages related to my business.

The problem is, is it possible to create a section on my main website that lists 4 latest posts from my blog that are installed in the subdirectory? I have searched all over the internet for the solution, but I've found nothing.

Can you tell me how can I solve this?

Comment: You could use the REST API to pull posts from the blog onto the main site, but it might be better to just create a single install. What led you to decide that separate installs may work best?

Comment: Use RSS widget to display posts on your main site. As per your setup, posts feed url would be `http://example.com/blog/feed`.

Comment: I decided to separate the blog because of SEO purposes. Because I decided to make the blog in multi-language, and I don't want it affected the main site. Is my choice to install the blog in different Wordpress installations is right, or should I stick to a single installation? I also don't want to change the permalink structure to have example.com/blog/ in all my blog posts.